# Could you please help me to find the error in my below sql code

Tags: sql

```
WITH unmatchedtrancounts AS
(
       SELECT 'rms.ordhead'            AS tablename,
              Count_big(etl_update_ts) AS todayrows
       FROM   rms.ordhead t1
       WHERE  t1.etl_update_ts >= CONVERT(DATE, Getutcdate())
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 'rms.shipment'           AS tablename,
              Count_big(etl_update_ts) AS todayrows
       FROM   rms.shipment t2
       WHERE  t2.etl_update_ts >=CONVERT(DATE, Getutcdate())
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 'rms.shipsku'            AS tablename,
              Count_big(etl_update_ts) AS todayrows
       FROM   rms.shipsku t3
       WHERE  t3.etl_update_ts >= CONVERT(DATE, Getutcdate())
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 'rms.sups'               AS tablename,
              Count_big(etl_update_ts) AS todayrows
       FROM   rms.sups t4
       WHERE  t4.etl_update_ts >= CONVERT(DATE, Getutcdate())
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 'rms.im_doc_head'        AS tablename,
              Count_big(etl_update_ts) AS todayrows
       FROM   rms.im_doc_head t5
       WHERE  t5.etl_update_ts >= CONVERT(DATE, Getutcdate())
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 'rms.tran_data_history'  AS tablename,
              Count_big(etl_update_ts) AS todayrows
       FROM   rms.tran_data_history t6
       WHERE  t6.etl_update_ts >= CONVERT(DATE, Getutcdate())
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 'rms.im_invoice_detail'  AS tablename,
              Count_big(etl_update_ts) AS todayrows
       FROM   rms.im_invoice_detail t7
       WHERE  t7.etl_update_ts >= CONVERT(DATE, Getutcdate())
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 'rms.tran_data_codes'    AS tablename,
              Count_big(etl_update_ts) AS todayrows
       FROM   rms.tran_data_codes t8
       WHERE  t8.etl_update_ts >= CONVERT(DATE, Getutcdate()))
SELECT Count(tablename) AS tablesloadedtodayfrom unmatchedtrancounts uwhere u.todayrows > 0
```

I am getting an error: `Incorrect syntax near unmatchedTranCounts`

Comment: Please, edit your question to format the code, to be more readable. Thank you.

Comment: Did you write all that code without trying it even once during the process?!?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm

Comment: Did you check your code at all to see where the error was?  I used SSMS and found it 2 typos.   If it works beyond that I do not know as you just asked to fix the one issue (posted as answer below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used SSMS to reformat it after I fixed 2 typos.  You had 2 in this line:

```
select count(tableName) as tablesLoadedTodayfrom unmatchedTranCounts uwhere u.todayRows > 0
```

You did not put a space before FROM and you need to remove the u  just before where.

```
WITH unmatchedTranCounts
AS (SELECT 'rms.ordhead' AS tableName,
           COUNT_BIG(etl_update_ts) AS todayRows
    FROM rms.ordhead t1
    WHERE t1.etl_update_ts >= CONVERT(DATE, GETUTCDATE())
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'rms.shipment' AS tableName,
           COUNT_BIG(etl_update_ts) AS todayRows
    FROM rms.shipment t2
    WHERE t2.etl_update_ts >= CONVERT(DATE, GETUTCDATE())
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'rms.shipsku' AS tableName,
           COUNT_BIG(etl_update_ts) AS todayRows
    FROM rms.shipsku t3
    WHERE t3.etl_update_ts >= CONVERT(DATE, GETUTCDATE())
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'rms.sups' AS tableName,
           COUNT_BIG(etl_update_ts) AS todayRows
    FROM rms.sups t4
    WHERE t4.etl_update_ts >= CONVERT(DATE, GETUTCDATE())
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'rms.im_doc_head' AS tableName,
           COUNT_BIG(etl_update_ts) AS todayRows
    FROM rms.im_doc_head t5
    WHERE t5.etl_update_ts >= CONVERT(DATE, GETUTCDATE())
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'rms.tran_data_history' AS tableName,
           COUNT_BIG(etl_update_ts) AS todayRows
    FROM rms.tran_data_history t6
    WHERE t6.etl_update_ts >= CONVERT(DATE, GETUTCDATE())
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'rms.im_invoice_detail' AS tableName,
           COUNT_BIG(etl_update_ts) AS todayRows
    FROM rms.im_invoice_detail t7
    WHERE t7.etl_update_ts >= CONVERT(DATE, GETUTCDATE())
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'rms.tran_data_codes' AS tableName,
           COUNT_BIG(etl_update_ts) AS todayRows
    FROM rms.tran_data_codes t8
    WHERE t8.etl_update_ts >= CONVERT(DATE, GETUTCDATE()))
SELECT COUNT(tableName) AS tablesLoadedToday
FROM unmatchedTranCounts
WHERE u.todayRows > 0;
```